# Multi window cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, multi-window

If there are multiple window in an application how do I pass values between them?

My first approach would be to create a NSWindowController for any window, and assign these controllers to the Application Delegate.

Am I on the right way? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your technique is fine. If you are creating a document-based application you can also do this in your NSDocument subclass.

Comment: I'm not in document-base app. In your opinion is better to create multiple xib or only a unique xib ?

Comment: If you use multiple xib files it can reduce memory usage, if you don't load them until you need them.